# How do you properly use the compareTo method implemented in String?

Tags: java, string, compareto

So I created a the employee object and a driver. The driver contains an ArrayList of Employees, and this particular method returns the Employee whose name comes first alphabetically.

Let's add two Employees to the ArrayList 'staff' and call them "a" and "z".

For some reason, it always returns the Employee "z" when I expect it to return Employee "a". Am I using the compareTo method correctly, or is it something else entirely?

```
 public Employee first()
    {
        int guy = 0;


        for ( int x = 1 ; x < staff.size() ; x ++ )
        {
            if ( staff.get( x -1 ) instanceof Employee && staff.get( x - 1 ).getName().compareTo( staff.get( x ).getName() ) < 0 )
                guy = x - 1;
        }

        return ( (Employee) staff.get( guy ) );
    }
```

Comment: What does the documentation say about how it works?

Comment: you haven't shown us the compareTo method implementation

Comment: Why don't you sort your list on some custom Comparator? And why is there a need to check `instanceof` at all?

Answer (score 2):

No need to reinvent the wheel. Make use of a custom comparator and use the `Collections` sorting methods.

```
public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Employee> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
    }
}

Collections.sort(yourArrayList, new NameComparator());
```

Alternatively, you can ensure your `Employee` class implements `Comparable<Employee>` and you can do without the custom comparator above. This assumes you will only ever want to compare based on names.